# ordering by name, day, date in mysql query?

Tags: sql-server

I have this input.

```
October 21 , 2010
October 14 , 2007
October 08 , 2010
March 19 , 2009
June 25 , 2009
June 21 , 2013
June 21 , 2013
June 19 , 2006
June 01 , 2009
July 26 , 2013
July 25 , 2012
July 23 , 2013
July 19 , 2013
July 01 , 2009
January 31 , 2013
January 23 , 2013
January 23 , 2011
January 19 , 2013
January 01 , 2000
February 17 , 2011
February 16 , 1998
December 25 , 2003
August 31 , 2013
August 04 , 2013
August 03 , 2013
August 03 , 2013
August 03 , 2013
April 26 , 2013
April 26 , 2013
April 19 , 2005
```

I want to order this so that the latest dates are on top.. but I can't seem to do it, can someone please provide a solution?

this is my sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Length(Year) > 7 AND `Title` 
LIKE '%" . $q . "%' AND `Genres` LIKE '%" . $genre . "%' AND `Actors` 
LIKE '%" . $actor . "%' AND `Year` <> 'Unknown' 
ORDER BY `Year` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Comment: So the date you have mentioned is coming from 3 different columns?

Comment: and where is your mysql query???

Comment: `ORDER BY Year DESC, month DESC,day DESC `

Comment: "April 19 , 2005" is one column

Answer (score 1):

So, this are 2 columns, right?

Then do it like this:

```
SELECT
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month_day_column, ', ', year_column), '%M %d, %Y') AS your_ISO_conform_date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY your_ISO_conform_date DESC
```

- read more about `str_to_date()` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).
- and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is some info about the format you have to supply as argument to `str_to_date()`

Comment: "April 19 , 2005" is one column in my db

Comment: Then it's even easier: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(your_column, '%M %d , %Y') as column_alias FROM yourTable ORDER BY column_alias`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using MySQL at work, mainly SQL Server, I've found this link within a second: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
select str_to_date('October 21 , 2010', '%M %d,%Y')
```